# Передача разных данных в один Fragment

Tags: android, navigation

Нужно в Navigation drawer (реализован в MainActivity) по нажатию на пункт меню R.id.menu1 передавать одну часть массива данных

```
list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Александр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Иван"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Петр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Николай"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Роман"));
```

, а по нажатию на R.id.menu3 передавать другую часть массива

```
    list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Инна"));
    list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Елена"));
    list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Людмила"));
    list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Ирина"));
    list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Виктория"
```

в один и тот же Fragment (First_Fragment()).
Подскажите как реализовать этот процесс передачи с помощью интерфейса. Спасибо

Код MainActivity:

```
package com.example.user.project7;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Toolbar myToolbar;
    DrawerLayout myDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    sendDataActivityToFragment sendDataActivityToFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.id_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        myDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.id_drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.id_nv_activity_main);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, myDrawerLayout, myToolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        myDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.id_fl_activity_main,
                    new First_Fragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.menu1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.id_menu_about:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Текст", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu1:
                fragment = new First_Fragment();
                sendDataActivityToFragment.sendData(1);
                break;
            case R.id.menu2:
                fragment = new Second_Fragment();
                break;
            case R.id.menu3:
                fragment = new First_Fragment();
                sendDataActivityToFragment.sendData(2);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Menu3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.id_fl_activity_main, fragment).commit();
        }
        myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    public interface sendDataActivityToFragment {
        public void sendData(int i);
    }

}
```

Код First_Fragment:

```
package com.example.user.project7;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class First_Fragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.sendDataActivityToFragment {

    List<WorkMan> list;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View v;
    private int flg;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (flg == 1) {
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Александр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Иван"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Петр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Николай"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Роман"));
        } else {
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Инна"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Елена"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Людмила"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Ирина"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Виктория"));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.id_rv_first_fragment);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(getContext(), list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(int i) {
        flg = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделай интерфейс MyFragmentInterfeis, с методом void addList(List<WorkMan> list). Имплементруй его в First_Fragment, и там уже его подавай в адаптер. В MainActivity сделай переменную MyFragmentInterfeis myFragment. В R.id.menu* делай проверку if (myFragment==null){myFragment = new First_Fragment()} после вызывай myFragmen,taddList(listMenu*).

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял добавил интерфейс в MainActivity и имплементировал First_Fragment, но данные не передаются. Что сделал не так?

Comment: Добавил в  MainActivity  public interface sendDataActivityToFragment {
        public void sendData(int i);
    }

Comment: Примерно как в ответе накидал сделай, там не очень все красиво конечно, но работать будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий код.
MainActivity:

```
package com.example.user.project7;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Toolbar myToolbar;
    DrawerLayout myDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    sendDataActivityToFragment mySendData;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.id_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        myDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.id_drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.id_nv_activity_main);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, myDrawerLayout, myToolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        myDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragment = new First_Fragment();
            mySendData = (sendDataActivityToFragment) fragment;

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.id_fl_activity_main, fragment).commit();
            mySendData.sendData("1");
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.menu1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.id_menu_about:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Текст", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu1:
                fragment = new First_Fragment();

                if (fragment instanceof sendDataActivityToFragment) {
                    mySendData = (sendDataActivityToFragment) fragment;
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException(fragment.toString()
                            + " must implement sendDataActivityToFragment");
                }

                mySendData.sendData("1");
                break;
            case R.id.menu2:
                fragment = new Second_Fragment();
                break;
            case R.id.menu3:
                fragment = new First_Fragment();

                if (fragment instanceof sendDataActivityToFragment) {
                    mySendData = (sendDataActivityToFragment) fragment;
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException(fragment.toString()
                            + " must implement sendDataActivityToFragment");
                }
                mySendData.sendData("2");
                //  Toast.makeText(this, "Menu3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.id_fl_activity_main, fragment).commit();
        }
        myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    public interface sendDataActivityToFragment {
        public void sendData(String s);
    }

}
```

И код фрагмента First_Fragment:

```
package com.example.user.project7;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class First_Fragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.sendDataActivityToFragment {

    List<WorkMan> list;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View v;
    private String flg;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (flg.equals("1")) {
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Александр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Иван"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Петр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Николай"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Роман"));
        } else {
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Инна"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Елена"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Людмила"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Ирина"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Виктория"));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.id_rv_first_fragment);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(getContext(), list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String s) {
        flg = s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Измени вот так:

```
 switch (id) {
        case R.id.id_menu_about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Текст", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.menu1:
                if(fragment==null){
            fragment = new First_Fragment();
               }
            sendDataActivityToFragment.sendData(1);
            break;
        case R.id.menu2:
            fragment = new Second_Fragment();
            break;
        case R.id.menu3:
             if(fragment==null){
            fragment = new First_Fragment();
               }
            sendDataActivityToFragment.sendData(2);
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Menu3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
```

И вот так:

```
@Override
public void sendData(int i) {
    flg = i;
if (flg == 1) {
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Александр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Иван"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Петр"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Николай"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Роман"));
        } else {
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Инна"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Елена"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Людмила"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Ирина"));
            list.add(new WorkMan(R.drawable.men1, "Виктория"));
        }
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(getContext(), list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

И

```
   @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.id_rv_first_fragment);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Добрый день. Сделал так как написано но получил ошибку:E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.project7, PID: 5080
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.user.project7.MainActivity$sendDataActivityToFragment.sendData(int)' on a null object reference... Что не правильно сделал?

Comment: Переменная fragment должна быть типа интерфейса: sendDataActivityToFragment fragment; в методе onNavigationItemSelected удали строчку Fragment fragment = null и поменяй sendDataActivityToFragment.sendData(*) на fragment.sendData(*)Попробуй теперь)